# How to return inner xml of child node as string during xml deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I'm working with deserializing large xml documents. For the most part, this is fine. I'm not concerned with some of the child nodes further down the tree, but they do contain data that I'd like to capture for possible use later, however I don't want to fully deserialize these. I'd rather take the entire node and store it as a string that I can later come back to.

for example, giving the xml doc below:

```
<item>
    <name>item name</name>
    <description>some text</description>
    <categories>
        <category>cat 1</category>
        <category<cat 2</category>
    </categories>
    <children>
        <child>
            <description>child description</description>
            <origin>place of origin</origin>
            <other>
                <stuff>some stuff to know</stuff>
                <things>I like things</things>
            </other>
        </child>
     </children>
</item>
```

I want to read in the *other* node, and store the inner xml as a string (ie "<stuff>some stuff to know</stuff><things>I like things</things>"). Make sense?

In my `item` class, I've tried various **System.Xml.Serialization** attributes on the other property with no luck such as `XmlText`, `XmlElement`, etc.

How do I accomplish this? It seems like it would be a fairly common task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by deserializing to an object of type `XmlElement` using the [`XmlAnyElementAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

So, as an example, these classes would work:

```
[XmlRoot("item")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("categories")]
    [XmlArrayItem("category")]
    public List<string> Categories { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("children")]
    [XmlArrayItem("child")]
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("origin")]
    public string Origin { get; set; }

    [XmlAnyElement("other")]
    public XmlElement Other { get; set; }
}
```

If you wanted the string value of the contents, you could read the `InnerXml` property. See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hTIcGF) for a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using the XmlDocument object you can use Xpath to query for different tags. Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx(v=vs.110).aspx) for a little more detail, but, using your example:

```
XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("/child/other");
Console.WriteLine(node.InnerXml);
```

Comment: I'm deserializing thousands of these objects using `XmlSerializer` and I think changing it to iteratively parse the file and build the objects would cause a severe perf hit.